# Circuits made using evolutionary algorithims (Solved)

Tags: pcb, circuit-design

Let me preface this by saying I am by no means an electrical engineer.

I am looking for an article that I saw some time back and wondering if there has been further research on the subject.

From what I understand a team of engineers created a circuit board by using algorithms based on theories of how neuronal connections in the brain form. Essentially the board made its own connections through the path of least resistance.

Basically the circuits that offered the least resistance and the best connection (don't know if that's redundant) were made stronger, and those that were less efficient "died off".

I know for a fact many new articles were written on it but as far as searching for more literature on it I am at a loss.

While [this](http://www.nature.com/news/neuroelectronics-smart-connections-1.14089) is close it's not exactly what I am talking about. They didn't "model" it on anything, they actually let it grow the connections itself.

Sorry in advance if this makes almost no sense, like I said I'm not an engineer.

EDIT: [This](http://phys.org/news/2015-09-electronic-circuits-artificial-evolution.html) is the exact article I was looking for. I understand the way I phrased this made it hard to understand but not being versed in electronics by any means made it hard for me to articulate what I was trying to say. So please stop saying "Has nothing to do with PCBs", "You made no sense". That is exactly why I put in the original question disclaimers about what I was asking.

Hope you guys enjoy the article.

Comment: Sounds like experiments done with slime molds. Except your version makes no sense, you can't arbitrarily make connections on a PCB.

Comment: Which is why I said "I am not engineer" at the beginning and "Sorry in advance if this makes almost no sense" at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People have been messing with this for a long time.

[Some amateur work](http://hackaday.com/2012/07/09/on-not-designing-circuits-with-evolutionary-algorithms/)

[Some university research, oft retold like an epic tale](http://www.damninteresting.com/on-the-origin-of-circuits/)

These are both based on genetic algorithms, which is passingly similar to neural networks. This may have caused some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Many novel antennas (multi frequency, etc.) have been been designed in this manner.  Actually, most microwave equipment is optimized using a Genetic Algorithm or some other optimization.  Basically, you design the circuit using imperically means (set trace width, lumped element filter components, cavity sizes, and so on) and the let an algorithm tune the EM chatacteritics.  Antennas, however, have been designed strictly as an evolutionary process.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolved_antenna

Answer (score -1):

I found it after searching through the reddit archives -.-

[Here](http://phys.org/news/2015-09-electronic-circuits-artificial-evolution.html) for anyone that is interested.

Comment: You didn't find it -- that has nothing to do with PCB's

Comment: Again why I prefaced it with "I am not an engineer". Obviously made a mistake in naming the title, but this is the article I was looking for.